# Are there color variables for various programming languages?

Tags: colorscheme, filetype-html, filetype-javascript, filetype-php, filetype-scss

I know, in Vim I can get a list with variables for color themes with the command `:hi`.
But there are not the programming languages I need.

Is there a way to get specific color variables for JavaScript, PHP, SQL, SCSS, HTML, C++, C etc. to create language specific color schemes?[image]

Thank's
Manny

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean by 'color variable'. Could you elaborate? Do you have a screenshot that could help us understanding what you xant to achieve?

Comment: vim comes with syntax highlighting files for programming languages few people have heard of. Which ones are you missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are!

Open a file of the language you want to see it‘s color variables.
In `vim MyController.php` for example, do `:highlight`.
Do that in the files of the specific languages you need.

Answer (score 3):

A "color scheme" is not language-specific. Every file will use the same color scheme. Here's [an old question with some good answers](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2782/how-can-i-create-my-own-colorscheme) on creating your own color scheme, though, if that's really what you are asking for.

It looks like what you want is to create your own syntax files for some out-of-the-mainstream language. The usual way is to pick an existing one that's similar to the one you want and modify it. If you'd prefer to start from scratch, the [Vim Tips Wiki has a page](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Creating_your_own_syntax_files) for that.